# Observe many times from same Observable (RxAndroidBle)

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I'm using the [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) library with RxJava2 to read from a BLE Characteristic. I think this question is just an RxJava question, but including the detail that I'm using `RxAndroidBle` in case that is useful.

I get connection, and then use it to call `readCharacteristic()`, which itself returns a `Single<ByteArray>`. At this point, I don't just want to just get the one `ByteArray` though. I need to read from this characteristic several times, because the BLE device is set up to let me get a small file back, and characteristics can only send 20 bytes back at a time, hence my need to read repeatedly.

Is it possible to modify this code so that the `switchMap()` below returns an `Observable` that will emit many `ByteArrays`, instead of just the single one?

I'm new to RxJava.

```
val connection: Observable<RxBleConnection> = selectedDevice.record.bleDevice.establishConnection(false, Timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
return connection
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .switchMap {
    // I want to get an Observable that can read multiple times here.
    it.readCharacteristic(serverCertCharacteristicUUID).toObservable()
  }
  .doOnNext {
    Timber.e("Got Certificate bytes")
  }
  .map {
    String(it as ByteArray)
  }
  .doOnNext {
    Timber.e("Got certificate: $it")
  }
  .singleOrError()
```

Comment: Of course it is possible. Questions are: 1. `Do you know how many times you need to read the characteristic to get the full value?`; 2. `How much time you need to give your peripheral between two consequent reads?`. As a note: if peripheral is configured correctly it is possible to execute a single read on the API level and the Android OS would perform as multiple reads under the hood as needed (with some limit which I cannot remember right now)—referrence `Bluetooth Spec Core v5.0, Vol 3, Part F. "Long Attribute Values"`.

Comment: 1. `I need to read until a specific value is returned` 2. `I don't believe I need to give the peripheral any time between reads, but I could be wrong`. I will try looking at the `notificationObservable` mentioned by Eduardo below, but I'm also curious how a Single<> can be turned into an Observable<> that returns many times (and then use something like takeUntil() to turn it off). Thanks for your library, and your help!

Comment: @DariuszSeweryn I'm going to look into the Long Attributes stuff, although it looks like support varies by chip. Indications or Notifications sound like a great solution as well, but I assume they need special setup on the device I'm connecting to. So ideally, I'd like to figure out how to perform those recurring reads on the chracateristic. I've tried wrapping it in Observable.onCreate(), and emitting the value of a blocking read on the characteristic, but the first read never goes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by sending a signal to stop both the `connectionObservable`, and the read on the Bluetooth characteristic. Of note is that you need to call `toObservable()` AFTER `repeat()` or this doesn't work, although I don't know why exactly.

```
override fun readMultipartCharacteristic(macAddress: String): Single<String> {
  val CERTIFICATE_TERMINATOR = 0x30.toByte()

  val device = bluetoothService.getBleDevice(macAddress)
  if (connectionObservable == null || !device.connectionState.equals(RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTED)) {
    connectionObservable = device.establishConnection(false, Timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  }

  val stop: PublishSubject<Unit> = PublishSubject.create()
  return connectionObservable!!
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .takeUntil(stop)
      .switchMap {
        it.readCharacteristic(UUID("my-uuid"))
            .repeat()
            .toObservable()
            .takeUntil(stop)
      }
      .collectInto(ByteArrayOutputStream(), { buffer, byteArray ->
        // Watch for the signal of the end of the stream
        if (byteArray.size == 1 && byteArray.get(0).equals(CERTIFICATE_TERMINATOR)) {
          stop.onComplete()
        } else {
          buffer.write(byteArray)
        }
      })
      .map {
        String(it.toByteArray())
      }
}
```

Comment: As for the positioning of the `.repeat()` it behaves differently when applied to a `Single` and to an `Observable`. In the former case it `Repeatedly re-subscribes to the current Single and emits each success value.` in the latter `Returns an Observable that repeats the sequence of items emitted by the source ObservableSource indefinitely.`. As a side note: it is possible to create an equivalent flow without the usage of a `PublishSubject`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it possible to rewrite this so that I don't have to close the connection to get it to stop though? If I close the connection, my peripheral stops advertising. So I need to prevent the connection from going away. I'm wondering if keeping a ReplaySubject around that is subscribed to the connection Observable would do the trick.

Comment: It is possible to keep the connection open but you would need to think on the higher level what you want to achieve. You create a parts of the flow as you have written above. You must only ensure that the `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()` is not unsubscribed. Wether you use `ReplaySubject`, `.publish()`, `.share()` is a secondary topic which depends on a specific use case. I tend to use `.publish()` and model the flow accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up having success with ReplaySubject, but I will look at .publish() as well.

Comment: This is really nice way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat a read multiple times until a specific value is emitted one needs to change this part:

```
// I want to get an Observable that can read multiple times here.
it.readCharacteristic(serverCertCharacteristicUUID).toObservable()
```

to something like what was [suggested by the RxJava author in the first answer that google gives for phrase `rxjava single repeat`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4155):

```
// this will repeat until a `checkRepeatIf` returns false
Observable.defer {
  val successValue = AtomicReference<ByteArray>()
  connection.readCharacteristic(serverCertCharacteristicUUID)
    .doOnSuccess { successValue.lazySet(it) }
    .repeatWhen { completes -> completes.takeWhile { checkRepeatIf(successValue.get()) } }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will try it out in the next day or two.

Comment: Dariusz, I tried the example you suggested, and it works. I'm able to collect the ByteArrays into a buffer, and stop repeating. However, the observable never completes, and I'm not sure why. https://gist.github.com/skykelsey/7898801f0c5b97dc88c40a976e8cc61c

Comment: It probably does not complete as the `.establishConnection()` does not complete on it's own. Only the `Observable` returned from a `.switchMap()` completes at some point.

Comment: Do you know what a good solution is? I've tried a bunch of was of trying to get the connection to complete, although I'm not sure I want that. I need to read several characteristics and return them together, and one of them at least requires this multiple read code. I've tried doing them in a more normal rx way, but I get errors because BT can't have parallel requests.

Comment: There is no silver bullet unfortunately. Every time you need to model how you would like the connection to behave. You may check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508618/how-to-respond-to-ble-characteristic-notifications-by-sending-a-new-write-comman) for insights as it seems to have a similar flow.

Comment: `RxAndroidBle` serializes most actions so requesting them in parallel shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I was doing something wrong, but I got crashes when I attempted parallel characteristic reads.

Comment: There may be many causes... Though it shouldn't be from a simple parallel execution.

Comment: I finally got it working and added the full solution. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notification to buffer your data.

```
device.establishConnection(false)
.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(characteristicUuid))
.flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable) // <-- Notification has been set up, now observe value changes.
.subscribe(
    bytes -> {
        // Given characteristic has been changes, here is the value.
    },
    throwable -> {
        // Handle an error here.
    }
);
```

Comment: My characteristic doesn't support the NOTIFY property. I assume I need to set this up on the other side of the connection?`Characteristic <redacted> supports properties: [ READ ] (2) does not have any property matching [ NOTIFY ] (16)`